# Saving a JSON object into a file in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I´ve read similar question regarding this and I can´t find a solution. I am converting a CSV xml file to a json array of objects. The following function does it succesfully:

```js
const csvtojsonV2 = require("csvtojson");

csvtojsonV2().fromFile('./CSV_TO_JSON/file.xml')
    .then((jsonObj) => {

        console.log(jsonObj)

    })
```

But now I´d like to get that jsonObj and put it in a file inside a folder in my current workspace:

```js
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

csvtojsonV2().fromFile('./CSV_TO_JSON/file.xml')
    .then((jsonObj) => {

        var folderNameJSON = uuidv1()
        folderNameJSON = 'JSON_CONVERTED'

        fs.mkdirSync(folderNameJSON)
        fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, folderNameJSON, 'file.json'), jsonObj)


    })
```

However when I open the file it just appears: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],etc...`

¿Is this how it supposed to be seen? How can I make it appear as an array of objects like it appears when I `console.log(jsonObj)` in the first code snippet?

Comment: did you try `JSON.stringify(jsonObj)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write in a file you have to convert your object to string.

Just use

```
let objString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, folderNameJSON, 'file.json'), objString);
```

Answer (score 3):

Before save to file convert json to string with JSON.stringify
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify